# Lots of movie clips make flash lags?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i created a game that has 96 still movieclips and seven more movieclips that basically move horizontally. The lag starts to rise if i add more and more moving movieclips. The game loop just basically, increment the x coordinate of the movieclips, so i don't think i have problems in the game loop.

Is it normal the flash will lag once it has exceeded certain number of movieclips??
if it's normal, what do you suggest to increase the game's performance?

anyway, this is the update method from the game loop:

```
public function update():void
    {
        //cek kondisi untuk melakukan spawn char
        spawnChar();

        //cek kondisi untuk melakukan spawn stand(stand diisi oleh pedangang di zona)
        spawnStand();

        //cek tiap char untuk tiap kondisi sekaligus assign depth yg sesuai;
        for (var i:int=0; i<mArrForeObjects.length; i++)
        {                               
            mArrForeObjects[i].update();
            if (mArrForeObjects[i] is Char && mArrForeObjects[i].x > mWorld.MAP_WIDTH * Tile.TILE_WIDTH || mArrForeObjects[i].x <  -  mArrForeObjects[i].width || mArrForeObjects[i].y > mWorld.MAP_HEIGHT * Tile.TILE_HEIGHT + mArrForeObjects[i].height || mArrForeObjects[i].y < 0)
            {
                //jika di luar peta, hapus char ini
                delChar(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

thx

Comment: Are all 96 movieclips on the display at once? Are the other 7 moving simultaneously? What is happening in spawnChar, spawnStand and delCar?

Comment: yes, it's on display at once. spawnChar, spawnStand basically just add movieclips based on certain conditions(it's just an if and couple addchild), and delChar just del movieclips. i don't think that the source of problem is in that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've solved the lag by loading picture as BitmapData and copypixel it to the screen 
reference : http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/7/2/Tutorial-AS3-The-basics-of-tile-sheet-animation-or-blitting/

Answer (score 1):

If you're just moving the display objects on the x-axis, you can try setting cacheAsBitmap to true to increase performance. Or, you can try redrawing bitmaps of each object from a shared bitmapData object. [Here is an interesting article with a performance test](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=290).